# Output one attribute at the time with to_str usage in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have a class with many attributes but need only one attribute at a time, i.e.

```
   class A
     attr_accessor :name
     attr_accessor :other1
     attr_accessor :other2
     attr_accessor :other3
     attr_accessor :other4
   end
```

And want the output of only one attribute at a time:

```
   a = A.new
   puts a.name.to_str
```

to be:

```
  name value of a: value_of_name
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: What does the method `a.name` do? You probably want to override the `to_s` method rather than add a `to_str` method - `to_s` is the method Ruby uses to determine the string representation of an object. Is it actually `a.to_s` that you want to be *Name for a..* rather than `a.name.to_s`?

Comment: How come you have a need to to_str on a name? Isn't a string already?

Comment: class A has many attributes, and with a.name.to_str I only want to obtain the name attribute in string format, as well as the name of the parent object.

Comment: I think he wants to change the way it is output.

Comment: I originally thought I understood this question... Where is the `name` method in all of this?

Comment: sorry... i wanted to make the question clearer...

Comment: updated my answer, take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

You wouldn't consider just creating a method in the class that does this for you?

```
def as_string(sym)
  "value of #{sym.to_s}: #{send(sym)}"
end
```

Then you could use `a.as_string(:attributename)` to get the result you want? Otherwise you're looking for an attribute to act as an object, and doing `attr_accessors` aren't really the way to go..

**Old Answer:**

You need to override the `to_s` method in the class definition. Note that this is implicitly called by `puts` - when a method expects a string, it will automatically attempt `to_s`, so you don't need to.

Comment: thanks. I see attr_accessors usage is limited for my purpose indeed

Comment: "Appreciation is more rewarding than any financial reward."

Answer (score 0):

In the A class create a to_s method.  This should override the default one.

e.g.

```
class A
def initialize
end

def to_s
puts "Name for a: #{name}"
end

end
```

Comment: I want to call to_str on the attribute name, not on the object a. is this possible?

Comment: Probably best to create your own method in this case that displays the name in your preferred format?

Comment: you mean, there is no other way than defining a class Name with custom to_str and include this into A ?

Comment: Name is pointing to a string object, the string object belongs to a string class with a to_str (or to_s) method- you could override the method here but it is not wise!

Comment: "Appreciation is more rewarding than any financial reward."